# How do I write a standalone application in Spark to find 20 of most mentions in a text file filled with extracted tweets

Tags: linux, scala, apache-spark

I'm creating a standalone application in spark where I need to read in a text file that is filled with tweets. Every mention starts with the symbol, "@". The objective is to go through this file, and find the most 20 mentions. Punctuation should be stripped from all mentions and if the tweet has the same mention more than once, it should be counted only once. There can be multiple unique mentions in a single tweet. There are many tweets in the file.

I am new to scala and apache-spark. I was thinking of using the filter function and placing the results in a list. Then convert the list into a set where items are unique. But the syntax, regular expressions, and reading the file are a problem i face.

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]){
   val locationTweetFile = args(0)
   val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("does this matter?").getOrCreate()
```

tweet file is huge, is this command below, safe?

```
val tweetsFile = spark.read.textFile(locationTweetFile).cache()
val mentionsExp = """([@])+""".r

}
```

If the tweet had said 
"Hey @Honda, I am @customer I love @honda. I am favorite @CUSTOMER." 
Then the output should be something like, ((honda, 1),(customer,1))

Since there are multiple tweets, another tweet can say, 
"@HoNdA I am the same @cuSTomER @STACKEXCHANGE." 
Then the Final output will be something like
((honda,2),(customer,2),(stackexchange,1))

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? And are you wondering if `spark.read.textFile` is safe or if caching a big dataset is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go step-by step.

1) `appName("does this matter?")` in your case doesn't matter

2) `spark.read.textFile(filename)` is safe due to its laziness, file won't be loaded into your memory

Now, about implementation:

Spark is about transformation of data, so you need to think how to transform raw tweets to list of unique mentions in each tweet. Next you transform list of mentions to `Map[Mention, Int]`, where `Int` is a total count of that mention in the RDD.

Tranformation is usually done via `map(f: A => B)` method where `f` is a function mapping `A` value to `B`.

```
def tweetToMentions(tweet: String): Seq[String] =
  tweet.split(" ").collect {
    case s if s.startsWith("@") => s.replaceAll("[,.;!?]", "").toLowerCase
  }.distinct.Seq

val mentions = tweetToMentions("Hey @Honda, I am @customer I love @honda. I am favorite @CUSTOMER.")
// mentions: Seq("@honda", "@customer")
```

The next step is to apply this function to each element in our RDD:

```
val mentions = tweetsFile.flatMap(tweetToMentions)
```

Note that we use `flatMap` instead of `map` because `tweetToMentions` returns `Seq[String]` and we want our RDD to contain only mentions, `flatMap` will flatten the result.

To count occurences of each mention in the RDD we need to apply some magic:

First, we `map` our mentions to pairs of `(Mention, 1)`

`mentions.map(mention => (mention, 1))`

Then we use `reduceByKey` which will count how many times each mention occurs in our RDD. Lastly, we order the mentions by their counts and retreive result.

```
val result = mentions
  .map(mention => (mention, 1))
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
  .takeOrdered(20)(Ordering[Int].reverse.on(_.2))
```

Comment: Why did you create mentions variable twice? distinct.Seq isnt part of Array the compiler said. And .flatMap(tweetToMentions) was unable to find encode for type string.